# VUE3 не обновляет дочерний компонент и не обновляет пропсы

Tags: vue.js, vue3

Есть такой компонент

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue';
import List from './List.vue';
import { User } from './types'

const items = ref([]);

fetch('https://dummyjson.com/users').then(response => response.json()).then(response => {
  items.value = response.users;
});


</script>

<template>
   <List :items="items" />  
</template>
```

почему то не обновляется `<List>` хотя я меняю `items` когда выполняется запрос.

```
<List
   :items="items"
/>
```

Comment: нужен полный код а лучше сделай кейс на https://play.vuejs.org/ а так вилами по воде

Comment: Вы не показываете сам List - тогда просто попробуйте поставить <List v-if="items" :items="items" /> - должно все появиться и все дело в асинхронности.